# Grape City Active Reports 11, exporting to excel duplicates rows

Tags: excel, activereports

We have a report that duplicates a couple of rows when we export it to excel.  When I step thru the detail_format method, there is only 1 record for the rows that are being duplicated.  Also, when I export to a pdf, it works fine.  For the duplicate rows, there is one column where the data is showing up on the next line.  So, I widened that column and it now exports OK.  This is fine for the current data, however, if the have wider data, it does it again.  The relevant properties on the textbox are:

```
CanGrow = True; 
CanShrink = False; 
MultiLine = True; 
WrapMode = WrapMode.WordWrap;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My bad the Last property is WrapMode = WrapMode.WordWrap;

Comment: I have tried it without the WrapMode and with it equal to WrapMode.CharWrap and WrapMode.NoWrap.  None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the WrapMode of the TextBox to None when exporting to Excel. This won't create another row for the column which has large data.

```
SectionReport1 rpt = new SectionReport1();
(rpt.Sections["detail"].Controls["textBox3"] as GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox).WrapMode = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.WrapMode.NoWrap;
rpt.Run();

XlsExport excelExport = new XlsExport();
excelExport.Export(rpt.Document, "../../SectionReport.xls");
```